# (Detailed) Fluctuation Theorems/Relations and their implied symmetry

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, statistics, stochastic-processes, non-equilibrium

I'm currently reading up on non-equilibrium statistical mechanics, in particular so-called *fluctuation theorems* or *fluctuation relations*.

In [Section 3.1.2 of arXiv:1205.4176](https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.4176), the author introduces the "detailed fluctuation theorem" (DFT) which relates the pdf of some quantity $\Omega$ via the relation

$$
\frac{p(-\Omega)}{p(\Omega)} = \exp(-\Omega).
$$

He further mentions:

> Such a symmetry constrains “one half” of the pdf which means,
> e.g., that the even moments of $\Omega$ can be expressed by the odd ones and vice versa.

This is where I don't exactly follow and would be happy if someone could clarify. I understand the first part, that one can get the distribution of e.g. negative values of $\Omega$ using the DFT and the pdf for positive $\Omega$. However, I don't understand the last part of the sentence how I can use the DFT to express even moments by the odd ones and vice versa.